# can I write semantic web markup for an external web resource?

Tags: annotations, semantic-web, rdfa

I am interested adding semantic markup details to some web content. Some of the content is public and I can reproduce, but a lot of the content is content I don't own and I don't want to avoid or get around copy right issues, by not hosting the content my self, and all I really want to do is markup the content, not reproduce it.

So is there some way for me to annotate or write semantic markup like RDFa and then point that scemantic markup information at an external resource?

Maybe by combining different technologies.

For example: 
I could try and write an XSLT document and add RDFA markup and point that at a XHTML document. But if I did do that would any or the search engines or SPARQL query engines still understand that. 
Or maybe there would be some other way to reference the external content with HTML5 imports or javascript and xpath.

Comment: You can state something on your page about things on external pages (e.g., "this company with the URI xyz has 4 employees"), but you want to do that without having to state "4" (as value for a employee property) anywhere on your page?

Comment: Basically yes, I am interested in keeping the information and meta data completely separate.  
An example of where I would be interested in trying this is with University units and articulation agreements between different universities.

Comment: After a lot of searching I found a language call EMML, Enterprise Mashup Markup Language, that looks like it would have been able to do what I want. But it looks like it is a dead language, because a lot of the links to the resources for it go to dead sites and I can't find any post on it newer than 2011.

Comment: Please have a look at [Web Annotation Vocabulary](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-vocab/).

Comment: Thanks Stanislav Kralin I think the Web Annotation Vocabulary is almost exactly what I am looking for. It looks like to would allow me to mark up and store the information about what I am referencing. But I couldn't find any information on SPARKL query engins I could use that could then fetch that data or that I could run against the Web Annotation Vocabulary mapping files once I did have all that information.

Comment: Also, please have a look at Ontotext [DSP](https://ontotext.com/knowledgehub/fundamentals/semantic-annotation/).